# Как создать ярлык на рабочем столе с Activity чужого приложения?

Tags: java, android, activity

В общем дело такое,нужно запустить Activity от приложения Meizu Account.
Приложение имеет название пакета:

```
com.meizu.account
```

У него есть Activity под названием:

```
com.meizu.root.OpenSystemRightActivity
```

Пробовал запускать Activity напрямую:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.meizu.account","com.meizu.root.OpenSystemRightActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Оно не работает,но другие Activity этого приложения запускает.
В маркете было приложение QuickShortcutMaker.Оно создает ярлык этого Activity на рабочем столе и запускает его.Что странно,оно запускается и работает.
Думаю через костыль сделать так же.
Как создать ярлык Activity чужого приложения?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, а это нормальное явление, что активити лежит вне пакета приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем,не получилось запустить Activity сразу напрямую,но получилось создать ярлык:

Указываем в AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Задаю обработчик щелчка:

```
 Intent shortcutIntent;
    shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.meizu.account", "com.meizu.root.OpenSystemRightActivity"));
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    final Intent putShortCutIntent = new Intent();
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"Root MEIZU");
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(OtherActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
    putShortCutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(putShortCutIntent);
```

Activity запускается через баг системы,после перевода интерфейса в "Легкий режим".
Без перевода интерфейса в "Легкий режим",Activity через созданный ярлык не будет запускаться.